# Could the Tiangong-2 dock to the ISS?

Tags: docking, docking-port, tiangong-2

As far I know, in the time of the MIR + Space Shuttle dockings it was a problem to solve.

Are their docking systems compatible?

Comment: Strongly related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/are-space-stations-compatible/

Comment: @peterh do you mean APAS-95?

Comment: @Mark Yes, although that post doesn't say, are the Tiangong-2 and the ISS compatible. Although likely they are, because Tiangong-1 used APAS-95 and also the ISS has APAS-95 ports, and it is unlikely that the Chinese would use different docking ports for their space stations.

Comment: @Prakhar Yes. I improved my comment. :-)

Comment: @peterh, actually, they're probably *not* compatible.  ISS and Tiangong-1 both have passive APAS-95 ports, and to dock two APAS-95 ports, at least one needs to be an active port.

Comment: @Mark Wow! It can be a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the docking systems in use on the ISS is a passive [APAS-95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgynous_Peripheral_Attach_System#APAS-95) system.  Tiangong-2 is [believed to also have a passive APAS-95 system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docking_and_berthing_of_spacecraft#List_of_mechanisms/systems) or something mechanically compatible.  In order for two APAS-95 adapters to connect, at least one of them needs to be an active adapter, so Tiangong-2 can't dock with the ISS, but a Shenzhou spacecraft could probably dock with either.

Comment: Only one of the APAS systems on ISS is presently available, and only for another year or so.  They are (or will be) all permanently covered.  The APAS on PMA-1 is used to connect Node 1 (Unity) to the FGB (Zarya), the APAS on PMA-2 already has an international docking adapter attached, and the APAS on PMA-3 will have such an adapter installed in about a year.